# I executed following code with macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I executed following code

```
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main( )
{
  int i, j, temp;
  i=5;
  j=10;
  temp=0;
  if( i > j)
    swap( i, j );
  printf( "%d %d %d", i, j, temp);
}
```

It gave me output as `10 0 0`

My question is why `#define` macro gets executed even after the `if(i>j)` statement is `false`?

Comment: Add {} in to macro body. `# define swap(a,b) { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; }`

Comment: Don't do that. Use a function not a macro. By doing `#define swap` you are creating a conflict with the C++ Standard Library's `std::swap` function and any other piece of code which provides a swap function.

Comment: Perhaps consider `#define swap(a,b,temp)  do { temp =a; a = b; b = temp;} while(0)`, so it's clear that this macro relies on a third variable, now you're assuming `temp` is available to you.

Comment: @unwind: you'd then use the macro like this: `swap(i, j, temp)`, or `float x, y, z; swap(x, y, z);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding braces to your macro helps in scoping your code.
When you write your macro without braces then it will get expand in this manner.

```
    if( i > j)
{
      temp=a; 
}
    a=b; 
    b=temp;
```

But when you add braces like this:-

```
#define swap(a,b) {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

Then your code will execute as per your expectation

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the macro into curly braces to make it work:

```
#define swap(a,b) {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

Your macro is expanded into the following

```
if( i > j)
  temp=a; 
a=b; 
b=temp;
```

And the proper solution is to use [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/), which is a template function. You'll never run into this kind of problems with template functions

Comment: The `do {..} while (false)` allow to use `;` after the macro correctly.

Comment: indeed, but you're not supposed to use this macro in the first place, just use std::swap

Comment: @Jarod42 So does this solution. Unless your compiler is **way** older than Turbo C++ an extra trailing semi-colon is simply ignored.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: `if (..) SWAP(..); else ;` is an error with simple brace. (result to `if (..) {..}; else ;` with the extra semi colon provoking an error)

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your macro like this:

```
#define swap(a, b) do { int temp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = temp; } while (0)
```

Note that here I declare `temp` inside the compound statement, if you have to deal with different (larger) types, you could declare the `temp` variable in another scope like you did.

Answer (score 1):

You need a scope in that macro:

```
# define swap(a,b) do { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; } while(0)
```

Note: The do/while is avoiding pitfalls if it used as an expression.

But that macro is junk, anyway. It requires the variable temp declared outside, which is leading to the confusion in the first place.

In C++ just use std::swap.

Answer (score 0):

Add braces for macro. It will work.

```
# define swap(a,b) { temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If to insert the macro definition in the code then instead of

```
  if( i > j)
    swap( i, j );
```

you will get

```
  if( i > j)
    temp=i; i=j; j=temp;
```

It will look more clear if to format this code appropriately

```
  if( i > j) 
    temp=i; 

  i=j; 
  j=temp;
```

So in realty the if statement was not executed.

However the two statements that follow the if statement were executed.

So j was assigned to i and i becomes equal to 10 while temp was assigned to j and j becomes equal to 0,

This result you got.:)

If you do not want this result then you should enclose the macro definition in braces. For example

```
# define swap(a,b) { temp=a; a=b; b=temp; }
```

However it would be better to define variable temp as a local variable. For example

```
# define swap(a,b) { int temp=a; a=b; b=temp; }
```

In `C++` you could use standard template function `std::swap`. The problem is that `C` has no references. Usually in C references are substituted for pointers. So the function could look as

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}
```

And in main you could call this function as

```
swap( &i, &j );
```

In `C99` you could define this function as inline

```
inline void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I was expecting. I was confused why result of if condition isn't considered